# Valgrind Invalid read/write list

Tags: c++, memory-management, valgrind

Even after a lot of research, I still don't figure out why I've got this error from valgrind..
There is a class spike (which implements a pseudo double linked list)

```
class spike
{
  int s_cell;
  int s_begin;
  int s_number;
  int s_type;
  spike *s_previous;
  spike *s_next;

  spike *s_origin; // pointer for original spike or itself
                   // (in the very first spike_data )

  spike *s_derive; // pointer for the spike in the derived class
                   // (note, that sometimes there are 2 or more high
                   // order spike_data in parallel; the pointer is only to one)
public:
  spike(int c, int b, int n, int typ=c_normal)
  {
    s_cell = c;
    s_begin = b;
    s_number = n;
    s_previous = NULL;
    s_next = NULL;
    s_derive = NULL;
    s_origin = this;
    s_type = typ;
  }

  ~spike()
  {
    kill();
  }
```

And class spike_data.

```
class spike_data
{
protected:
  int sd_mode;
  int sd_size;
  int sd_number;      // the whole number of spikes 
  int sd_file;        // the number of files for analysis
  int *sd_file_name;  // the names of files used in the analysis
  int sd_cells;       // the whole number of different cells

  spike **sd_array;   // array of all spikes
  spike *sd_first[c_maxcells]; // array of the first entries of spikes
  spike **sd_file_st; // spikes in array for indication of beginning of the new files

// And here is the part that's getting the error
// (it is happening when i try to release)
void spike::kill()
{
  // delete a cell from all references and t becomes "dead"
  // actual release of memory is done in renumerate
  try
  {
    if (s_previous != NULL)
      s_previous->s_next = s_next;
    if (s_next != NULL)
      s_next->s_previous = s_previous;
    if (s_origin && s_origin != this)
    {
      int tmp = 1;
    while(tmp == 1) {
        if (s_origin != NULL) {
            if (s_origin->s_derive != NULL) { // LINE 674
                if ( s_origin->s_derive != this ) { // LINE 675
                        s_origin=s_origin->s_derive;
                    }
                    else tmp = 0;
                }
            else tmp = 0;                       
                     }
             else tmp = 0;
    }

        s_origin->s_derive=NULL; // LINE 685
    }
  }
  catch (...)
  {
  }
  s_next = NULL;
  s_previous = NULL;
  s_origin = NULL;
}


spike_data::~spike_data()
{

if(sd_array!=NULL)
{
    for(int i=0;i<sd_number;i++)
        delete sd_array[i]; // LINE 697

    delete[] sd_array;
    sd_array=NULL;
}
if(sd_file_st!=NULL)
{
    delete[] sd_file_st;
    sd_file_st=NULL;
}
if(sd_file_name!=NULL)
{
    delete[] sd_file_name;
    sd_file_name=NULL;
}
}
```

Sorry if the code is indigest, it's not mine, but it's still ok...

```
Invalid read of size 4
==2079==    at 0x806B0DF: spike::kill() (spikes.cpp:674)
==2079==    by 0x8067D26: spike::~spike() (spike.h:288)
==2079==    by 0x806B174: spike_data::~spike_data() (spikes.cpp:689)
==2079==    by 0x805CB1F: spike_anal::~spike_anal() (spikea.cpp:151)
==2079==    by 0x8061C1E: statistical_analysis(spike_group*, spike_data*) (spikeg.cpp:264)
==2079==    by 0x804B37E: calculate_something(int, int) (all.cpp:422)
==2079==    by 0x8059805: real_main(int, char const*) (simple.cpp:742)
==2079==    by 0x804DC20: main (hello.cpp:66)
==2079==  Address 0x5d8f534 is 28 bytes inside a block of size 32 free'd
==2079==    at 0x4023881: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:387)
==2079==    by 0x806B17C: spike_data::~spike_data() (spikes.cpp:697)
==2079==    by 0x805CB1F: spike_anal::~spike_anal() (spikea.cpp:151)
==2079==    by 0x8061C06: statistical_analysis(spike_group*, spike_data*) (spikeg.cpp:264)
==2079==    by 0x804B37E: calculate_something(int, int) (all.cpp:422)
==2079==    by 0x8059805: real_main(int, char const*) (simple.cpp:742)
==2079==    by 0x804DC20: main (hello.cpp:66)
==2079== 
==2079== Invalid read of size 4
==2079==    at 0x806B0EC: spike::kill() (spikes.cpp:675)
==2079==    by 0x8067D26: spike::~spike() (spike.h:288)
==2079==    by 0x806B174: spike_data::~spike_data() (spikes.cpp:689)
==2079==    by 0x805CB1F: spike_anal::~spike_anal() (spikea.cpp:151)
==2079==    by 0x8061C1E: statistical_analysis(spike_group*, spike_data*) (spikeg.cpp:264)
==2079==    by 0x804B37E: calculate_something(int, int) (all.cpp:422)
==2079==    by 0x8059805: real_main(int, char const*) (simple.cpp:742)
==2079==    by 0x804DC20: main (hello.cpp:66)
==2079==  Address 0x5d8f534 is 28 bytes inside a block of size 32 free'd
==2079==    at 0x4023881: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:387)
==2079==    by 0x806B17C: spike_data::~spike_data() (spikes.cpp:697)
==2079==    by 0x805CB1F: spike_anal::~spike_anal() (spikea.cpp:151)
==2079==    by 0x8061C06: statistical_analysis(spike_group*, spike_data*) (spikeg.cpp:264)
==2079==    by 0x804B37E: calculate_something(int, int) (all.cpp:422)
==2079==    by 0x8059805: real_main(int, char const*) (simple.cpp:742)
==2079==    by 0x804DC20: main (hello.cpp:66)
==2079== 
==2079== Invalid write of size 4
==2079==    at 0x806B10A: spike::kill() (spikes.cpp:685)
==2079==    by 0x8067D26: spike::~spike() (spike.h:288)
==2079==    by 0x806B174: spike_data::~spike_data() (spikes.cpp:689)
==2079==    by 0x805CB1F: spike_anal::~spike_anal() (spikea.cpp:151)
==2079==    by 0x8061C1E: statistical_analysis(spike_group*, spike_data*) (spikeg.cpp:264)
==2079==    by 0x804B37E: calculate_something(int, int) (all.cpp:422)
==2079==    by 0x8059805: real_main(int, char const*) (simple.cpp:742)
==2079==    by 0x804DC20: main (hello.cpp:66)
==2079==  Address 0x5d8f534 is 28 bytes inside a block of size 32 free'd
==2079==    at 0x4023881: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:387)
==2079==    by 0x806B17C: spike_data::~spike_data() (spikes.cpp:697)
==2079==    by 0x805CB1F: spike_anal::~spike_anal() (spikea.cpp:151)
==2079==    by 0x8061C06: statistical_analysis(spike_group*, spike_data*) (spikeg.cpp:264)
==2079==    by 0x804B37E: calculate_something(int, int) (all.cpp:422)
==2079==    by 0x8059805: real_main(int, char const*) (simple.cpp:742)
==2079==    by 0x804DC20: main (hello.cpp:66)
```

So here it is. When i want to kill spike_data,each time I call delete sd_array[i] , which calls destructor of spike => kill()
The thing is this code bug at the end. It used many times during the execution and at some point,when all computations are done and need to release memory, it doesn't work. I think there is problem when i put s_origin->s_derive=NULL. but can't seize it...

If u need more code just ask :)

Thank you a lot for those who are courageous enough to get into this code !!

Good week end

Nico

Comment: OMG Please work on your code looks before posting ! I'm editing it

Comment: don't get why code style doesn't work for the first lines of the classes. Sorry. Or are u talking about the style ? Yeah it's really a torture i agree. i ll try to change this piece of code into better looking one.. it's from a russian^^

Comment: I changed it. It's better.

Was failing because of newline absent ^^

Comment: Can you place each statement to separate line and regenerate valgrind output? Also, can you rewrite long `a && b && c ...` condition into tree of `if`s (`if(a) {\n if(b) {\n if(c) {\n}\n } \n}`), each on new line?

Comment: Are you sure that s_origin is still valid? If s_origin of element B points to another, previous object A in that array, A would be already deleted when B is deleted and the pointer B->s_origin would be invalid at that point.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld : but normally s_origin (of your element A), once kill() called, is NULL, so the first condition (s_origin != null) when B calls kill() does not hold anymore so it shouldn't go farther, and it shouldn't try to access s_origin->s_derive ... no ?

Comment: But maybe this is the problem, it's not recognizing well the NULL value .. ? I saw that there is a difference between the null (c) and the NULL (c++). Valgrind report this on linux platform (and others), but seg fault appears only on mac os (and not on linux). it's a hint but dunno what to do here...

Comment: I've found something ... in the memory, when it has reached s_origin->s_derive , s_derive is a 32 bits before where it should be. the value in the supposed address of s_origin->s_derive is 0x00 so seg fault.. But how come it's doing it only at the end ...? and how is it possible ? elements are aligned, and the class takes a fixed size no ? (ie each element is a fixed size,and placed at a relative given addresse no ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good likelihood that the **default copy constructor for spike** has been invoked without you noticing it.  If this is the case, the first destructor may run correctly, but the second call will cause valgrind to dump messages like what you have posted.

In order to see if this is the case, if you are using C++11, add:

```
public:
  spike( const spike& rhs ) = delete;
```

and your code should fail to compile indicating that the need for you to write your own copy constructor.

If you are **not** using C++11, you can write your own copy constructor and place a breakpoint inside to see if it stops there while debugging.

Comment: I've created a copy constructor like this spike::spike( const spike& rhs ){ } and put a break as u said on it, but the program never stops, so it doesn't call any copy constructor ... :/ thx anyway !!

Comment: the original programmer uses lots of memcpy cmd (instead of copy constructor : old code) . Ex : dop = new spike*[sd_size];             memcpy(dop,sd_array,sizeof(spike*)*sd_number);                        I will work on that, it could be that.

Comment: Place breakpoints on spikes.cpp:689 and spikes.cpp:697 - when you hit the breakpoints print out the memory location being released.  Then change the breakpoints to a conditional breakpoints to stop when the variable is that address again.  When it hits that point a second time, go up the callstack and you will see the problem.  You have a deterministic memory bug here - should not be difficult to debug (unless you have nasty spaghetti code in your callstack).  You will have to use your eyes and brain a little to catch this one.

Comment: what you are suggesting me to do ... Isn't it the same thing as valgrind did and showed it to me in its output ... ??